# This code snippet causes variables to give me a syntax error afterward

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, if-statement

My code starts with:

```
pcperception = input("What is your character's current perception?")
if pcperception == ("1"):
  prange = (1)
elif pcperception == ("2"):
else:
  prange = (1)
print ("your range is " + str(prange)`
```

and if I add a variable via input afterward

```
tommy = input("What is your name?")
```

It tells me that my syntax is incorrect in declaring the variable.
But if i get rid of the top code, the bottom works.

Comment: Typo - missing parentheses `str(prange)\``

Answer (score 3):

It is because of your `elif` statement. There is no body to it. You can change it to this (depending on what you want it to do):

```
pcperception = input("What is your character's current perception?")
if pcperception == ("1"):
  prange = (1)
elif pcperception == ("2"):
  prange = None
else:
  prange = (1)
print("your range is " + str(prange))
```

I declared `prange` in the `elif` statement, because otherwise it may be the case that you try to use a variable later on that is not yet defined.